# Passing named variable to nested function in R

Tags: r, keras, r-package

I am developing an R package that uses some python pointers that I would like to delay until run-time as opposed to build-time. To achieve this, I am wrapping the initial function in another function with the following code:

```
residual_layer <- function(...) custom_residual_layer()(...)
```

And the custom residual layer is:

```
custom_residual_layer <- function() keras::Layer(
  classname = "ResidualUnit",
  initialize = function(filters=1, strides=1){
    super()$`__init__`()
    self$main_layers = list()
    self$skip_layers = list()
    self$filters = filters
    self$strides = strides
  },
  build = function(input_shape){
    self$main_layers <- list(
      keras::layer_conv_3d(filters = self$filters, kernel_size = c(3,3,3), strides = self$strides,
                    padding = 'same', use_bias = F),
      keras::layer_batch_normalization(),
      keras::layer_activation_relu(),
      keras::layer_conv_3d(filters = self$filters, kernel_size = c(3,3,3), strides = 1,
                    padding = 'same', use_bias = F),
      keras::layer_batch_normalization()
    )

    self$skip_layers <- list()
    if(self$strides > 1){
      self$skip_layers <- list(
        keras::layer_conv_3d(filters = self$filters, kernel_size = c(1,1,1), strides = self$strides,
                      padding = 'same', use_bias = F),
        keras::layer_batch_normalization()
      )
    }
  },
  call = function(inputs, ...){
    Z <- inputs
    for(i in c((seq_along(self$main_layers))-1)){
      Z <- self$main_layers[[i]](Z)
    }

    skip_Z <- inputs
    for(i in c((seq_along(self$skip_layers))-1)){
      skip_Z <- self$skip_layers[[i]](skip_Z)
    }
    return(keras::activation_relu(Z + skip_Z))
  }
)
```

Within the custom residual layer, I need to be able to change the default values of the filters and strides. This works as expected if I use integers, such as:

```
model <- keras::keras_model_sequential() %>%
keras::layer_conv_3d(filters = 64, kernel_size = c(7,7,7), strides = c(2,2,2), padding = 'same',
                    use_bias = F, input_shape = c(91,109,91,1))

model %>% residual_layer(filters = 2, strides = 2)
```

However, if I try to use a variable with the same value, as in `model %>% residual_layer(filters = filters, strides = strides)`, where `filters = 2` and `strides = 2`, then I get the following error:

```
Error in py_resolve_dots(list(...)) : 
  ..2 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

I am not sure why the integer works but the variable does not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, but it is a bit of a hack. I changed the original function so that the variables are globally defined when it is called and added the arguments to the nested function:

```
residual_layer <- function(filters, strides, ...) {
  filters <<- filters
  strides <<- strides
  custom_residual_layer()(..., filters, strides)
}
```

The problem here is the scope, I have had similar issues with for loops inside R functions where the only way to access a variable from inside the loop was to declare is globally. I am open to other (better) suggestions that avoid global declaration.